# C++: Running an algorithm for an amount of time (without chrono)

Tags: c++, timing

I was thinking of something like:

```
// Runs algorithm() n times during an amount of seconds.
void run(int seconds) {
  clock_t start = clock();
  clock_t current = start;
  while(double (current - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC <= seconds) {
    algorithm();
    current = clock();
  }   
}
```

I chose `clock()` over `time()` to avoid accounting time when the process sleeps.
I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this, without using *chrono*.

Comment: You could use a higher precision, platform-specific tool such as `QueryPerformanceCounter`, or experiment with [Boost's Timers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/timer/doc/index.html), though I don't know if the underlying implementation is better or not.

Comment: Do you want a portable solution or platform specific solution?

Comment: Why would anyone want to avoid `std::chrono`?

Comment: @bames53 C++11 is not an option in this case, nor Boost.

Comment: What specific problems do you have with your approach above that require a "better" way?

Comment: None, I just wanted to know what are some better methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STLSoft has a [performance_counter](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/classplatformstl_1_1performance__counter.html) which works on UNIX and windows platforms. The library is header only and only requires a simple include:

```
#include <platformstl/performance/performance_counter.hpp>

void run(int seconds) {
  platformstl::performance_counter pc;
  platformstl::performance_counter::interval_type current = 0;
  pc.start();
  while ((current / 1000) <= seconds){
    algorithm();
    current += pc.stop_get_milliseconds_and_restart();
  }
}
```

You could also look at the source for hints on making your own.